# XPages: Generate CSV file and attach to mail

Tags: csv, xpages, export-to-csv, icalendar, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying to generate a csv file (specifically an .ics) and attach this to an email.
The Email is composed via an SSJS-Function.
An opportunity could be to generate the csv file, save it to a document and attach this to the email .

I tried to generate the csv file via an XAgent in a XPage (like this http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8248MT) and get a handle of the output, but with no success.

Do you know a possibility to manage this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you are looking at 2 tasks:

1. Create a csv / ics file
2. Send this as attachment

For #1 you can use a Stringbuilder or a Printwriter or whatever. However an [ics file](http://filext.com/file-extension/ICS) is actually **not** a CSV file, but an iCalendar format. To generate it I highly recommend [ical4j](http://ical4j.sourceforge.net/introduction.html). In any case whatever you write -> don't create a file. Use a PrintWriter (for the CSV) that uses a ByteArrayOutputStream (or directly for ICS4J), so the result is a ByteArray in memory.

For #2 The ONE mental step you must make is AWAY from "the Notes way" trying to deal with embedded objects etc. You create a MIME message (there are snippets on OpenNTF) and create a mimepart. There you can use [setContentFromBytes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SETCONTENTFROMBYTES_METHOD_MIMEENTITY_JAVA.html) and you have your attachment.

Pro tip (to make your life easier): create a Java class with a function that takes an outputstream as parameter that generates the file for you. This way you can test it in Eclipse (or the Domino Designer Java view) without having to run preview and with full debugging support (you simply provide a file-output stream for testing and write to a file - or to System.out)